# Graphical nature of signal energy

Tags: signal, energy, math, function

In signals, we learn that the energy of a signal is the integral of its square.

E.g.

\$E=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2(t) dt\$

We know that integrals are the areas under the function in a graph. But what is the graphical representation of the energy of a signal? Or is the integral of a square just a purely algebraic thing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_(signal_processing))? It is a *definition* (and not derivation) and is analogous but not the same as energy in physics. You might also want to read [this](http://www.songho.ca/dsp/signal/signals.html)

Answer (score 0):

[image]Rotate the graph about the 't' axis, and you end up with a volume enclosed that is proportional to the energy.

Comment: Where does the square come in here? Could you elaborate more?

Comment: In numerical integration, the area under the graph is the sum of the slices of area x.dt.  Consider that for each 'dt' the 'x' value rotates to define a disc, of area π.x^2, volume π.x^2.dt,  so the total volume is the sum of those discs is equal to the integral of the square of x multiplied by π.

Answer (score -1):

Square of what? power? no just the integral.

\$E=\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(t) dt\$

For electrical: **Yes** it is signal squared **only for V,I** but not P all of which are time-variant signals.

\$\frac{V_{(t)}^2}{R}\$ = \$I_{(t)}^2R=P_{(t)}\$  yes then the square law applies only to **"certain signals except power signals"**  (  mechanical, acoustic pressure, thermal, electrical, nuclear, gravitational)

Integrals from Calculus 101 is just the area under the curve.

Comment: Energy of signal is not the same as energy in physics.

Comment: It is exactly the same,  It must be a voltage or current signal.  Yet we know x(t) can be defined as a power signal.  So "Physics" teaching is making assumptions not given in the question. i.e. anytime assumptions are not given, it is vague.  V*I=P is a rectangle ∫V(t)*I(t)dt could be a rectangle if constant, otherwise just the area.

Comment: Signal is not necessarily voltage or current. It can be acoustic or optical signal. Or an abstract mathematical function. Yes, the energy is defined in analogy with physics, but it is not the same.

Comment: True it could be , but it can also be a power signal in uW in which case the terms are vague. It could be a pressure signal in Pascal or a momentum signal in mv

Comment: Tony, take the time to click on the link @EugeneSh. provided in his comment to the original question. The term "energy" means something different in the field of signals & systems than it means in physics (or dc circuits).

Comment: There ought to be no difference.  The contradictions in that link are obvious to me.  Not you?  All examples are signals being a function of time " Yet power and power signal are treated differently. "Power  signal is not limited in time. It always exists from beginning to end and it never end .. and thus infinite energy"  I see a contradiction in terms for the use of SIGNAL and I state this logic is false. 
 This generalization that all signals must be squared regardless of value even though Power is a function of time and can have a start and end in time.

Comment: I guess they have NOT considered the contradiction even with stored power and reactive energy being non-infinite for any form of energy, mechanical etc inertial gravity etc. So the definition of "Signal" is vague to make this generalization true.